# Intro to Probability Airplane

Tags: probability

It turns out that my friend and I are boarding on the same plane. We are both
travelling on economy class, and this plane has 10 single and 10 double (a total of 30) economy seats. Assuming the seat assignments happened completely randomly, what is the probability that I will sit next to my friend on a double seat?

I know that there are 30! ways to sit everyone on the place. For person 1 (me) there are 20 possible ways to sit in a double seat. Then my friend has 1 option of where to sit. So I said that the Probability if (30 choose 2)*10( for number of double pairings) *(2 for ways in which 2 people can sit in two seats. Then I multiplied by 28! ways that everyone else can sit on the plane I divided this all by 30!.I got 10. Which cleary is incorrect. Any suggestions on where I went wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Forget about everyone else but your friend. Start with yourself. There are 10 single seats, so your only good options are double seats, meaning there 20 seats available for you. The chance of you getting a double seat is $20/30$. Then your friend needs to sit next to you which happens with probability $1/29$:

Answer: $\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{29}\approx 0.022$. Sorry, looks like you'll be sitting apart.

Comment: Oh yeah, I cluttered it more than necessary.+1.

Answer (score 0):

The probability both are in a double is $\frac{20}{30}\times\frac{19}{29}$. If they are both in a double the probability they are in the same row is $\frac{1}{19}$ (Suppose you sit first, there are $19$ available empty doubles and only one next to you).

Therefore the probability is $\frac{20\cdot19}{30\cdot29\cdot19}$